# Лучше выбрасывать исключение или возвращать null?

Tags: kotlin, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa

Какой подход лучше, обычное приложение spring boot mvc на kotlin, выбрасываем исключение и его обрабатываем, например при поиске данных в БД, или можно всегда возвращать null и уже его обрабатывать.

Comment: Возвращать null не самая лучшая практика, лучше всего выбрасывать исключения и обрабатывать их. Вы можете создавать сколько угодно кастомных исключений, которые будут яснее объяснять возникшую проблему.

Comment: Спасибо, просто на старом проекте использовали подход с исключениями, тут на Kotlin типа можно обходиться без

Answer (score -2):

Обработка исключений производится на сервисном уровне, ниже приведен пример кода, написанного с помощью spring boot и hibernate, где создается запрос в базу данных для поиска сущности Person по его id, с помощью метода getPersonById класса personRepository(который как раз и производит общение с бд).

Как видно в примере, мы создаем запрос и проверяем выходные данные, при значении null выбрасываем исключение PersonByIdNotFoundException, которое мы написали сами и которые наследуется от RuntimeException.

```
  public Person findById(int id){
            if (personRepository.getPersonById(id) == null){
                throw new PersonByIdNotFoundException(id);
            }
            return personRepository.getPersonById(id);
        }
```

Comment: да, но в kotlin мы можем сделать так:
fun findById(int id) : Person?  = personRepository.findByIdOrNull(id)
или 
fun findById(int id) : Person  = personRepository.findByIdOrNull(id) ?: throw Exception()

Comment: При запросах к бд лучше выбрасывать Excaption. Возможно это вам поможет разобраться что и когда лучше возвращать в методах http://codehelper.ru/questions/269/new/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE

Comment: Пример кода так себе, при валидном ID метод `getPersonById` будет всегда два раза вызываться.